# Raster Image Lines QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, raster

Looking to create the ESRI George Washington style set in QGIS. It is only avaliable as a .stlyx but the png's are available. Is there a way to set the length of the raster image to the segment length of a line or polygon edge?

Additional Information:

this shows what it should look like in Arc and also a link to the png images.
https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=191ef05f8bd844c68eee365ada32561b

Downloaded a ArcGIS Pro trial to see what I should get in Arc.
[image]

QGIS 3.16 view with points can be played about with and polygon fill can as well. Lines seem to be the biggest issue.
[image]

QGIS settings as follows, with a rotation of 90 degrees for the line so it runs along the line.

[image]

Comment: Please post some images of what you currently have, as well as what you would like to end up with.

Comment: Have just added some images. Wanting to make it into a QGIS style so I can use it beyond the ArcGIS Pro trial.